# sencha touch repeated task

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to move a panel from bottom to up. smoothly. for this i try this code.

```
Ext.define("mathmania.view.Main", {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
requries: [
    'Ext.util.DelayedTask'
],
xtype: 'panel',
config: {
    autodestory: true,
    border: 1,
    html: 'test panel',
    bottom: 0,
    centered: true,
    padding: 10,
    margin: '2%',
    width: '95%',
    listeners: {
        painted: 'countdown'
    }
},
countdown: function()
{
    var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {
        this.setBottom(this.getBottom + 5);
        task.delay(100);
    });
    task.delay(0);
}
```

but each time it works only once not for multiple time as a repeating task?. for moving this float panel smoothly is there any better way or what i missing in this code?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using do-while loop, Panel is moving two times now but still the objective is unachieved. I think i am lacking somewhere in loop.
Hope this helps a little bit.

```
        Ext.define("mathmania.view.Main", {
        extend: 'Ext.Panel',
        requries: [
            'Ext.util.DelayedTask'
        ],
        xtype: 'panel',
        config: {
            id: 'main1',
            autodestory: true,
            border: 1,
            html: 'test panel',
            bottom: 0,
            centered: true,
            padding: 10,
            margin: '2%',
            width: '95%',
            listeners: {
                painted: 'countdown'
            }
        },
        countdown: function()
        {
            var a=Ext.getCmp('main1');
            var i=0;
            var j=20;
            do{
              var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {
              a.setBottom(a.getBottom() + 10);
                task.delay(500);
                    });
               task.delay(1000);
               i++;
            }while(i<j)
        }
     });
```

Comment: If any one gets proper solution,please do share here.